# How to return many values in which.min() function in r

Tags: r

I am not sure how to return several values when we use which.min() function.

For example,

```
> tmp <- c(1,2,1)
> which.min(tmp)
> [1] 1
```

Above example, I want to get one and three.

How can I to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`?which.min`:

> giving the index of the **first** minimum or maximum respectively of x.

You could use:

```
tmp <- c(1,2,1)
which(tmp == min(tmp, na.rm = TRUE))
[1] 1 3
```